# Restrict div width to single child element's width

Tags: css, image, html, width, caption

I'd like to use image captions and since the `figure` tag is not supported in IE8 or below, I thought a `<div>` containing `<img>` and a caption would help out.

However, when my caption is wider than my `<img>`, the containing `<div>` width expands to the caption width. This causes ugly whitespace next to the `<img>`. Instead I'd like the caption to break over lines.

I could manually set the `<div>` width equal to the `<img>` width. Or manually insert a `<br />` in the caption where needed. But I was hoping there would be a more elegant solution.

For an example, please see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RubenGeert/uNDRx/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Working Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/uNDRx/3/

CSS:

```
div.rimg {
    display:table;
    width:1px;
    float:right;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius:5px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:10px;
}
div.rimg img {
}
div.rimg span {
    margin:10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<h2>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus</h2>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class='rimg'>
            <img src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/116120595/tree_1_200_200.jpg' alt=''><span>What an exceptionally beautiful tree</span>
        </div>et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks a million! Surprised that it works... since `overflow:hidden`, I'd expect only `1px` of the `img` to be visible...

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to be of help to you. You can safely remove `overflow:hidden;` I left it there since I wanted to do minimal changes in case you had a use case for it. On table displays, overflow works only on fixed layout tables, in the code above, if you add `table-layout: fixed;` to `div.ring`, then the overflow will be hidden and the width of the `div` will be 1px!

Comment: OK, no more sleepless night for me then :-) I combined `overflow:hidden` with `border-radius` in order to provide any `<img>` with slightly rounded corners. Which works fine now!